# Is there any open source libraries can get all values of getters of a java bean?

Tags: java, javabeans

Java code:

```
class X {
    private String aaa;

    String getAaa() {
        return aaa;
    }

    void setAaa(String aaa) {
        this.aaa = aaa;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         X x = new X();
         x.setAaa("hello");

         // how to populate the property names and values from instance 'x'?
         Map<String, Object> nameAndValues = someUtil.getPropertyNameAndValues(x);

         // it will be:
         // aaa -> hello
    }
}
```

Although we can get all getter methods and invoke them by reflection manually, I wonder if there is any open source library has already provided this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [BeanUtils.describe(java.lang.Object)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#describe%28java.lang.Object%29) from apache commons beanutils.

```
Map<String, Object> propertyValueMap = BeanUtils.describe(x);
```

But this only works if you fulfill the java bean specification - getters and setters must be `public`

```
class X {
    private String aaa;

    public String getAaa() {
        return aaa;
    }

   public void setAaa(String aaa) {
        this.aaa = aaa;
    }
}
```

See the java tutorial on [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html).

> To define a property in a bean class, supply public getter and setter methods.

Comment: I tried it, it's strange it doesn't provide the name "aaa" and value "hello"

Comment: @Freewind the getters and setters are not public

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html)  in java.bean package

Sample Code

```
for (PropertyDescriptor pd:
     Introspector.getBeanInfo(bean.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors())
{
      pd.getReadMethod();

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider use [apache beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/)

> It is natural to then access these methods directly, using calls to
>   the corresponding getXxx and setXxx methods. However, there are some
>   occasions where dynamic access to Java object properties (without
>   compiled-in knowledge of the property getter and setter methods to be
>   called) is needed

Answer (score 1):

The [`java.beans`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html) package already provides such a feature. This is built-in. Have a look at the [JavaBeans information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/) provided by Oracle.